# Where is the specification for the ARM assembler language used by arm-none-eabi-as?

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

I've downloaded the `arm-none-eabi-as` assembler from the [ARM website](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads).

It can assemble code such as the following (taken from [here](https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/blob/master/uart01/vectors.s)):

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl notmain
hang: b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

Where can I find the spec for this assembler language? I.e. where's the spec that defines what `.globl _start` means?

Comment: Have you tried reading the assembler's [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/)?

Comment: @fuz you are pointing to a GNU `as`; however, the syntax in the original question does not look like AT&T style which GNU as accepts by default. It is possible that another assembler program is used.

Comment: @kvu787 With which program do you assemble the example? Have you tried looking through the help output of that program (`asm --help` or smth similar)? It may have further references to the literature describing the language.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: There's an AT&T syntax for ARM assembly? I thought it was relevant only for x86. The code in the question looks like valid code for GNU's ARM assembler to me.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov There is no AT&T syntax for ARM.  This is most definitely the syntax accepted by the GNU assembler.

Comment: @fuz, Michael thanks, it is clear now. However, the AT&t syntax is used not only for x86 targets (as its origin is clearly not bound to Intel processors), but, as it turns out, not by all targets supported by the GNU toolchain.

Comment: It is gnu assembler, fuz pointed at the manual you need to read.  for example https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html#Global which simply declares that symbol as a global (so it can be seen outside this file/context/object).

Comment: why are we talking about AT&T syntax, that is just silly, the destination on the left or right predates 8086 much less AT&Ts mangling of the intel syntax.  arm with very few exceptions is destination on the left add r0,r1,r2 is r0 = r1 + r2, and so far the various assemblers support that (arm, gnu, etc).  has nothing to do with AT&T or intel or others.  Various assembly language syntaxes go back to when an assembler was a human with paper and pencil and the code was loaded with switches.  (and they could write it however they wanted).

Comment: I happened to have used .globl here for no real reason, maybe because it is strange, and the first way I learned it, you can use .global as well (just try it).  In languages like C a function (label) is global unless otherwise specified, in assembler or at least gnu assembler labels are local unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @old_timer Well, you might want to check out the Go tool chain's ARM assembler if you want to be weirded out a little bit.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool that reads it.  so anyone can make whatever asm they want so long as they produce proper machine code, wouldnt be too surprised if someone made a mangled one...

Comment: note _start is just a label, normally nothing special, but the linker complains if you dont have that label in one of your objects.  It will still link without it.  The gnu tools have an interest in that label at least for this target, other tools may have a different label or additional labels they look for.

Comment: being baremetal as in the linked example a notion of an entry point or other similar address doesnt make sense.  if building an application on an operating system then the loader may care to know what the entry point is to branch into the program.

Comment: @fuz Do you want to add your comment as an answer? I'll accept it then. Otherwise, I'll add the answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU assembler manual is reference document for the syntax of the language. It is found [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Syntax.html#Syntax). However, it is maybe not the easiest way to learn the syntax, and it intentionally abstracts away from any particular target.

There are some HOWTOs written by third-party authors, but a lot of them focus on Intel x86, which may confuse when trying to apply obtained knowledge to ARM targets. A promising manual that I have found and that is dedicated to using `as` for ARM targets is [here](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs3221/labs/assembler-intro.pdf).